# Why does mongo not apply limit and skip before fetching

Tags: mongodb

I wrote a query in mongo db that uses an index (both for the query as the sort part). If I explain the query I get:

```
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor state_1_lastModified_-1",
"scanAndOrder" : false,
"indexOnly" : false,
"stats": 
"LIMIT" -> "SKIP" -> "FETCH" -> "IXSCAN"
```

Why is mongo not able to skip and limit on the index before the fetch? 
I know I could use a range query to avoid using limit and skip.

Comment: Without fetching data firstly, it is no hard to know the whole data set, and no way to skip and limit

Comment: If the index already covers the the query predicates, it should not fetch the document before skip and limit, doing so makes skip/limit very slow/inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your filter conditions are completely satisfied by the index, then the query planner should SKIP before FETCH.  This was actually reported to the mongodb folks, and they had resolved it in https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13946.  The fix was backported.  It's present in 3.4.X starting from 3.4.19, 3.6.X starting from 3.6.9, 4.0 starting from 4.0.3, and 4.1.X starting from 4.1.2.  That is, if you're on "3.6" release branch, then you need at least 3.6.9 to see the change.

Comment: Cool, I haven't been working with mongodb lately but I tried it out with 3.6.23 and the SKIP happened before the FETCH. Thanks for the link to the mongodb ticket.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just for simplicity.

Assume db.collection has following documents

```
{x: 1, y: 1}
{x: 2, y: 3}
{x: 3, y: 4}
```

**QUERY1**

db.collection.find().sort({x: 1}).skip(1).limit(2)

stage chain can be `IXSCAN ==> SKIP ==> FETCH ==> LIMIT`

**QUERY2**

db.collection.find({x:2, y:3}).sort({x: 1}).skip(1).limit(2)

stage chain must be `IXSCAN ==> FETCH ==> SKIP ==> LIMIT`

So for simplicity, all case can be implemented as `IXSCAN ==> FETCH ==> SKIP ==> LIMIT`.